# How to prevent running "updb" twice for upgrading Media

Tags: 8, media, upgrading

I'm upgrading my custom media modules to use the "**core media**" in Drupal 8.4.8

I have to run the command `"drush [sitename] updb"`  twice in order to recognise my custom media modules code has been upgraded.

The first run - it show me an error, I need to upgrade my custom media modules to be compatible with the core media.  However, if I run the same command again, it then show me a list of the updates is going to run.

My question, Why I have to run it twice to get it recognise my custom media modules has been updated.  This will also caused a problem during deployment, because the deployment only run this command once.

Comment: Can one trigger database updates from hook_update_N itself?

Comment: I'll try that @leymannx